# How can the rate of convection up a chimney be computed?

Tags: thermodynamics, convection

I have various physics textbooks, but none of them explain exactly how to compute the rate of convection.

I assume that Newton's Law of Cooling should be used by I can't figure out how to apply it to the situation of a chimney.

For example, imagine we have a furnace and the gases of combustion are being produced at a temperature of 1200F and the ambient air temperature is 72F. The flue of the furnace is 12" in diameter. Let us imagine that the flue is just big enough to accommodate the gases of combustion. Assume that the chimney is 30 feet high.

What will be the airflow up the chimney in cubic feet per minute?

Comment: Newton's Law of Cooling has nothing to do with this. It's a complex *fluid dynamics* problem.

Comment: Convection is notoriously hard to compute from first principles. Look for empirical relations obtained from similar geometries ([example](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0735193320302670)).

Comment: The rate of convection up a chimney will be strongly dependent on the ability of outside air to make up for the air that goes up the chimney.  In turn, that depends on how tightly sealed the house is.  If you can't quantify how tightly the house is sealed, you will not be able to answer this question.

Comment: @DavidWhite For the purposes of the question, assume air pressure in the room is constant.

Comment: Roughly speaking, there are two relationships in the link that help to estimate the flow rate: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_effect

Comment: Based on The Tiler's comment it seems there is one piece of information missing from the original question: the height of the chimney, which I have added.

Comment: Fluid flow like gases and liquids in channels are described by solutions to Navier-Stokes equations. Setting up those solutions is more like an engineering problem than basic physics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on one of the comments, I found that there is a draft flow rate equation as follows:

[image]

where:

```
Q   = stack effect draft flow rate, ft3/s
A   = area, ft2
C   = discharge coefficient (usually from 0.65 to 0.70)
g   = gravitational acceleration, 32.17 ft/s2
h   = height or distance, ft
Ti  = average inside temperature, °R
To  = outside air temperature, °R
```

From this we can see that the average inside temperature is a key quantity that will differ from the burning temperature of the fuel. As makeup air enters the furnace or fireplace, it mixes and cools those gases to a considerable degree, so to answer the question we have to estimate the temperature of the exhaust gases. Based on [a table with some typical figures](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/fuels-exhaust-temperatures-d_168.html) we can see that a residential oil burner has exhaust gases of temperatures around 560F and a fireplace would be somewhat lower, maybe more like 400F.

If we plug these numbers into the equation we find that for an oil furnace the draft rate would be about 900 CFM, and for a fireplace would be about 800 CFM.

Comment: That equation is ubiquitous in the field, yet the associated assumptions, scope, and limitations aren't typically mentioned. It's reported to be derived by Barre, H. S.; Sammett, L. L. *Farm Structures*. John Wiley, 1950, pp. 180-181 and Bruce, J. M. Natural ventilation by stack effect. *Farm Building Progress* 1973, 32:23-27, but I haven't been able to find copies of these references. A comprehensive discussion appears at [Heiselberg, "Modelling of Natural and Hybrid Ventilation."](https://vbn.aau.dk/ws/portalfiles/portal/65753147/Modelling_of_Natural_and_Hybrid.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

As the comments indicate, this is not a straightforward physics problem. You'd want a computer simulation or some empirical data tables with entries similar to whatever situation you're working with, and much more information than you've provided.

However, given just the power output of the furnace, the chemical composition of the fuel, and an oxygen sensor in the exhaust pipe, this is a pretty straightforward chemistry problem.

Compute enthalpy of reaction.

Divide power by enthalpy of reaction to get the number of reactions per second.

Multiply reactions per second by the molar proportion of all the reactants for the exhaust gases from combustion.

Multiply the oxygen required in the reagents by (roughly) 4 parts nitrogen per one part oxygen in air. This is the amount of room air going out with the exhaust, if the $O_2$ sensor isn't activating.

Add all the reactants plus the nitrogen. The sum (with appropriately selected units) is the molar flow rate of exhaust.

If you want to convert to volumetric flow rate of exhaust through the outlet, measure the exhaust temperature at the outlet, assume standard pressure, and use the ideal gas law.

Comment: One of the comments links the key equations, specifically the "draft flow rate equation". That is kind of what I was looking for.